# Can not inject class into interace in Test

Tags: c#, nunit, unity-container

I have simple `HomeController`, in which DI occurs. 
When I start application and debug `HomeController` constructor, `SomeService` is not null what means that everything works.

```
private ISomeService SomeService;

public HomeController(ISomeService SomeService)
{
   this.SomeService = SomeService;
}
```

Then I have test, where injecting does not work. Unity, which I use for DI, does not inject  `SomeService` into `ISomeService`. In debug it is `null`. I mention that in Unity.config everything is configured properly.

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    private ISomeService SomeService;
    private HomeController controller;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        controller = new HomeController(SomeService);
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case you will either have to mock the interface manually and inject it into the subject under test or create a container specifically for the test. I lean more to mocking the interface so that the unit test is isolated.

Comment: I do not want to use mock, cause I do not want to isolate test. I need to test it exactly the same like in browser, but without opening  it. This is only for me to save my time. Good idea is to use sth like 'Container.Resolve'.

Comment: I would suggest then to research integration testing.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are passing

```
private ISomeService SomeService;
```

into `HomeController` constructor

```
controller = new HomeController(SomeService);
```

It will be *null* because you haven't initialized "SomeService" anywhere in the code

What would you like to Unit test? `HomeController` or `SomeService`?

If you wish to Unit Test `HomeController` you should mock `ISomeService` so that `HomeController` doesn't depend on service.

I suggest using Moq framework to mock `ISomeService` and test `HomeController` in isolation.

[Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

In the simplest way you can init `ISomeService` like:

```
private ISomeService SomeService = Mock.Of<ISomeService>();
```